# Restricting running time in SICStus Prolog

Tags: sicstus-prolog

Is it possible to restrict the running time of a query in SICStus Prolog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `time_out` predicate :

http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.7.1/html/sicstus_42.html